# .NetCore 2.0 with SSO and Post Login Validation

Tags: asp.net-core, single-sign-on, openid-connect

I'm developing a website with .Net Core that uses OpenIdConnect Single-Sign-On.

**Here is what I've accomplished so far:** the end-user goes to my website, they click login, and they are forwarded to the IDP (the login page hosted on another website). Upon successful login, they are redirected back to my site with user information.

**Here is where I'm struggling:** Once the user is forwarded back to my website, I want to do extra validation. For example, based on the staff number (which I receive back from the IDP) I want to make sure they have access to this website. If they do, I want to allow them in (which is easy). But if they don't, *I want to log them out and display an error message* (I don't know how to do this).

I've hooked onto the OnTicketReceived event (which I receive after a successful authentication from the IDP). I can access the data needed and do validation, but *specifically I'm not sure how to deny access*.

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "IDP Address";
            options.ClientId = "CLIENT ID";
            options.ClientSecret = "CLIENT SECRET";
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            options.Events.OnTicketReceived += OnTicketReceived;
        });
    }
    private async Task OnTicketReceived(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.TicketReceivedContext ticketReceivedContext)
    {
         //Check to see if user has access, and continue or stop login
         ticketReceivedContext.Fail(); //Doesn't seem to do anything 
         ticketReceivedContext.HttpContext.Abort(); //This works but resets the connection

         //Doing nothing logs the user in successfully
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In OnTicketReceived you want to do two things.

1. Redirect them to a page that will explain they do not have access. E.g. `ticketReceivedContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/AccessDenied")`. This page will need to allow anonymous access.
2. Call `ticketReceivedContext.HandleResponse()` to prevent the normal signin logic from completing.